# Can't use nested routes with React-Router and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'd need some help on how to use React-router with browser history and with Webpack. Everything works ok until the point I need to use nested routes, that's when I get 404s on my bundle.js.

Without history (with #s in url) everything works ok, but I'd prefer to go without them. I went as far as to use proxy server (code below), which does solve the problem but also means I can't seem to use all the other Webpack stuff I need (like postcss etc.). At least I wouldn't know how.

So I would really like to get this thing working using Webpack to deal with my postcss, React-router with nice and clean urls and with nested routes. Doesn't look too promising so far...

Here's my webpack config file (es6 syntax):

```js
import path from 'path';
import HtmlwebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

import postcssImport from 'postcss-import';
import nested from 'postcss-nested';
import mqpacker from 'css-mqpacker';
import cssnext from 'postcss-cssnext';

const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
const ROOT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname);
const APP_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'app');
const BUILD_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'public');

const common = {
  entry: [
    APP_PATH + '/App.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: BUILD_PATH,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        /* loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader',*/
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap!postcss-loader'),
      },
    ],
  },
  postcss: function(webpack) {
    return [
      postcssImport({
        addDependencyTo: webpack,
      }),
      nested,
      mqpacker,
      cssnext(),
    ];
  },
};

if (TARGET === 'dev' || !TARGET) {
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      inline: true,
      progress: true,
    },
    plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css'),
      new HtmlwebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Hohohohoho',
        template: BUILD_PATH + '/index.html',
        inject: 'body',
      }),
    ],
  });
}
```

...which works ok, but without ability to use nested routes. Here's then again something I tried with node and got it working, but then fail with using postcss with Webpack:

```js
require('babel/register')({});
var server = require('pushstate-server');

server.start({
  port: process.env.PORT || 8090,
  directory: './public'
});

var WebpackDevServer = require("webpack-dev-server");
var webpack = require("webpack");

var compiler = webpack(process.argv[2] == 'hot' ? require('./webpack.config.hot.js') : require('./webpack.config.babel.js'));
var devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {

  stats: {colors: true},
  contentBase: 'http://localhost:8090/',
  publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/js/',

  hot: process.argv[2] == 'hot'
});

devServer.listen(8080, "localhost", function() {})
```

Someone told me to use historyApiFallback but that didn't seem to change anything at all, but it's there in the webpack options nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add `history` argument to your Router:

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

render((
  <Router history={history}>
    {/* some routes */}
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

More about [`createBrowserHistory()`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#createbrowserhistory) in the docs.

Make sure you have `history` module installed: `npm install history`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly the bit which I fail to get working. Like I wrote, without history everything works all good but then I need to have those ugly #s in my url. With history things fail when I have nested routes, example.com/blaah works just fine but example.com/blaah/bleeh doesn't work anymore...

Comment: show me your routes, and I'll be able to help. In the meantime you can have a look at my [playground example](https://github.com/knowbody/react-router-playground). You can see the webpack settings and play around.

Comment: Is this related to https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2303 ? If so, I also couldn't figure out how to use history and render non-root components. The docs mention that I need to setup the server (https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0-rc3/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server) but they don't tell me how to do that. They mention express but unfortunately I know nothing about express. For now I decided to remove history = {createHistory()} from the <Router> because I just can't figure out how to use it.